# Undefined greater than expressions, java

Tags: java

Currently writing a code in java to play the card game "War." An error that I have is:

> The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s)
>   `Class<capture#1-of ? extends Card>`, `Class<capture#2-of ? extends Card>`
>     The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s)
>   `Class<capture#3-of ? extends Card>`, `Class<capture#4-of ? extends
>   Card>`"

The code I have written is this (and the same for the "<" expression)

```
if (player1Card.getClass() > player2Card.getClass()) {
    player1Cards.addLast(player2Card) ;
    player1Cards.addLast(player1Card) ;
```

How can I define the less than and greater than symbols? Im not sure where to put the definitions and Eclipse is only showing the error message.

Comment: Why do you compare the class ?!? What are you trying to achieve ? Normally classes are only compared with `=` and not `<` or `>`

Comment: Java does not support user-defined operator overloading (unlike C++ for the example). You need to approach your problem in a different way.

Comment: What type are `player1Card` and `player2Card`? You'll want that type to implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) **or** you can create a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for that **type**.

Comment: I think we need more information about what you're actually trying to do.  The code you given really makes no sense.  What are you expecting to accomplish by comparing the class?

Comment: Why should a class be greater or less than another class?

Answer (score 1):

`player1Card.getClass()` returns an object of Type `Class`. Java cannot compare classes with the `>` operator. You cannot redefine operators in java.

You could, however, compare the lenghts of the classnames like this:

```
if (player1Card.getClass().getName().length() > player2Card.getClass().getName().length()) {...
```

Or you can define your own comparison-method:

```
if (greaterThan(player1Card.getClass(), player2Card.getClass()) {...

// and somewhere else in the same .java file:
public boolean greaterThan(Class clazz1, Class clazz2) {...
```

Or, more sophisticated, write a `Comparator` for classes.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you are asking has to do with ordering, you can implement the Comparator interface.  Then, you can simply do compare(object1, object2), which will return a negative integer for the case object1 < object2, a 0 for the case object1 == object2 or a positive integer for the case object1 > object2.